# shell script containing ldapmodify - hardcoding commands

Tags: linux, shell, active-directory, ldap

I'm trying to run an ldapmodify command in a shell script, but I don't want to specify an external file containing commands (-f flag). This would just be for convenience - the commands in the external file would be dynamic, so it would be nice to avoid writing a new file every time the shell script ran ldapmodify. I would want the script to essentially enter the following into the command line:

```
prompt/> ldapmodify -v -H LDAP://111.111.111.11 -D "CN=binding_user,DC=example,DC=com" -x -w password
> dn: CN=group_name, OU=Groups, DC=example, DC=com
> changetype: modify
> add: member
> member: CN=Smith\, John, OU=Users, DC=example, DC=com
> (user presses Ctrl-D)
```

Anyone know of how to do this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use a "here" document:

```
ldapmodify .. <<!
dn: dc=example,dc=com
changetype: modify
replace: description
 -
add: description
description: The new description
!
```

For example.

Comment: Are you saying that would look like: "ldapmodify -v -H LDAP://111.111.111.11 -D "CN=binding_user,DC=example,DC=com" -x -w password <<!
dn: dc=example,dc=com
changetype: modify
replace: description
 -
add: description
description: The new description
!" ? What about the EOF character? Is that accounted for?

Comment: The `!` on a line by itself signifies the end of the here document and the end of file.

Comment: If this answer is correct, it should be marked as the answer.

Answer (score 4):

You can just echo the text and pipe to ldapmodify, like this:

```
echo "dn: CN=group_name, OU=Groups, DC=example, DC=com
changetype: modify
add: member
member: CN=Smith\, John, OU=Users, DC=example, DC=com" | \
ldapmodify -h <server:port> -D "cn=binding_user,DC=example,DC=com" -c -x -w <password>
```

Comment: The "HERE" doc approach works great, but in the context of a bash script, it introduces a trailing space when modifying a `userPassword`. This `echo` `pipe` approach does not produce the trailing space side effect.

Answer (score 0):

n2studio was 100% correct. 'echo' worked for me.  Also tested with ".. | sudo ldapmodify ..."  Please mark as the answer. (I wasn't allowed to comment, not got 50 points.)

Comment: This was a long time ago for me - did the accepted answer not work for you?

Comment: I just tested Terry Gardner HERE script answer. It also works okay. These are 2 solutions.